# How to find all sums of two sets in O(nlogn) time (arithmetic and comparisons)

Tags: algorithm

If sets A, B are subsets of {1, ..., n}, how would I find all elements of the set {a + b: a ∈ A, b ∈ B} in O(nlogn) time (arithmetic and comparisons)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This question has a classic solution using `FFT`.

`FFT` stands for [Fast Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) but can be used in order to multiply two polynomials in `O(n log n)` where `n = max length (Highest power)`.

Let's create two polynomials from sets `A` and `B`, each will be the sum of `x` to the power of an element in the set, `∑ x^a | a ∈ A`.
Now multiply these two using `FFT` in `O(n log n)` time since each polynomial highest power can't exceed `n`.

The powers of the new polynomial are exactly the new set! Since `x^a * x^b == x^(a+b)`.

Comment: And as an extra, one gets the number of ways each sum can be formed. These will be the corresponding coefficients.